# Overriding or changing the ExitProcess function in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, overriding

Is there any way that I can override or change the ExitProcess function in C++ that when I call the function it will go to my code?
I thought about taking the address of the function and putting my function in there but I can't realize how to do that?
any suggestion to how can I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have [std::atexit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit).
I just tried this and it works, at least for normal program terminations:

```
void at_exit_handler() {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Howdy", L"Howdy", MB_OK);
}

// register the exit function at program start:
std::atexit(at_exit_handler);
```

If you want to intercept the ExitProcess call and prevent the normal exit procedure you perhaps need to take a look at [Debug Hook Function Writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-hook-function-writing?view=vs-2017).

Comment: this doesn't work with ExitProcess and I meant to replace the ExitProcess function with my function so the process wont exit.

Comment: I see. Added info.